# Android Null object reference on location

Tags: java, android, gps, location

Okay so I am using this GPS location from [GPS.class](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2mkyjok6mpna2yw/GPS.java?dl=0) and I keep getting Null Object reference and not sure why.Here is my code:

```
 boolean permissionGranted = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    if(permissionGranted)
    {
        if (GPS.sharedInstance(AppDashboard.this).canGetLocation() && GPS.sharedInstance(this).isPermissionEnabled()) {
            double lat = GPS.sharedInstance(AppDashboard.this).getLatitude();
            double lon = GPS.sharedInstance(AppDashboard.this).getLongitude();
            Log.e(TAG, "Location: " + lat + "/"+ lon);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't get GPS locations");
        }
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 200);
    }
```

My Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

My Logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
at com.gpsApp.utility.GPS.getLatitude(GPS.java:113)
```

And GPS Class 113

```
public double getLatitude() {
    if (_locationManager != null) {
        _latitude = _location.getLatitude();
    }

    return _latitude;
}
```

Comment: On which line you get Null object reference?
Please add some stacktrace.

Comment: Can you post your 'com.gpsApp.utility.GPS.java' class? Where and how is '_location' variable initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `public double getLatitude()` from your `GPS` class, however the `_location` variable is not initialized hence you get the NullPointerException.

Prior calling `getLatitude()` try calling the `public Location getLastKnownLocation()` from your `GPS` class. This call will initialize the `_location` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line

```
boolean permissionGranted = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
```

**Instead of this**

```
 boolean permissionGranted = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
```

Comment: The problem isn't with that line, it is with the GPS line 113.